# Using multiple KeePass databases with separate configurations

Tags: windows, backup, keepass, multiple-instances

We are using KeePass (2.16, Windows) to store passwords in our company (let's name it KeePass_Corp). Additionally I am using another installation on a USB-stick to store my private passwords (KeePass_USB). As we have two different databases this works well except for the config. It seems as if KeePass stores its config somewhere central. Whenever I configure a plugin I use on both versions of KeePass the configuration of the other is overwritten.

An example: I am using a plugin to make backups whenever I save my database. I use this plugin on both installations. When using KeePass_Corp I configure a local folder as backup destination. If I now start my KeePass_USB the configuration of this version has the same backup location although it was configured to use the stick. This annoys because my private backups are now stored on the company drives.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and mention which operating system you use and which KeePass versions. Do you have a portable KeePass on the USB stick or just the database file?

Comment: I added the version and operating system (2.16 and Windows). i am using two installations of KeePass with two seperated databases. One is installed on the corporate PC and the database is also located there. The other is a portable version on my USB-stick with my own database also on the stick.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try the KeePass Forum. I found multiple posts about using multiple databases, but not exactly your issue. http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/search/?q=multiple+databases

Comment: Try to use KeePass 1.27 portable for KeePass_USB.